# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'maketrans' - PyCharm

Tags: python, python-2.7, base64, pycharm, urllib

I've got this strange problem on my PC with Python 2.7 + PyCharm 2016.2 + Windows 10 (64).

While running script:

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *

url = raw_input('Enter -')
if (len(url) < 1):
    url = "http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_292106.html"
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
lst = list()
tags = soup('span')

for tag in tags:
#    print 'TAG:', tag
#    print 'URL:', tag.get('href', None)
#    print 'Contents:', tag.contents
#    print 'Attrs:', tag.attrs
    num = int(tag.contents[0])
    lst.append(num)
print sum(lst)
```

I've got such message:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe E:/python/coursera/following_links.py
23
0.8475
Traceback (most recent call 
  File "E:/python/coursera/following_links.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 30, in <module>
    import base64
  File "C:\Python27\lib\base64.py", line 98, in <module>
    _urlsafe_encode_translation = string.maketrans(b'+/', b'-_')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'maketrans'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Same situation occurs in WingIDE.

Funny is, that while using python's Idle this script works.

Also it works on my second PC with Windows 8 (64) (Python 2.7 and PyCharm 2016.2)

Comment: Do you have a `string.py` in your PyCharm project directory?

Comment: Thx for help.
I did have my "own" string.py in project directory.
I'm morron :(

Answer (score -1):

I think this is happening behind the scenes. In order to carry out your commands, Python has to do some work and it is not finding the files it needs. That might explain why it may work in Idle and on your PC but not in others like Wing IDE.